# How many copies of this string is needed?

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two string, `A` and `B`, the goal is to to create `A` by concatenating copied of `B`. However before concatenating you can remove any number of characters, the order still remains the same though. Find the minimum number of copies of B needed to generate A. Return -1 if it is not possible.

Example: A = "ZAZA", B = "BAZ", could be done like `"##Z + #AZ + #A# = ZAZA"`, so the answer is 3.

---

I am thinking through the problem right now, I think the trick is do a sliding window and cover as much of A as possible with B in each iteration.

```
public int algorithm(String A, String B){
   int sol = 0;
   int aPtr = 0; // indicates where in A we are

   while(aPtr < A.length()){
     sol++; // we are using a new copy of B
     int curIndexInB = B.indexOf(A.charAt(aPtr++));
     if(curIndexInB == -1) return -1; // cant create A using B
     while(curIndexInB < B.length && aPtr < A.length()){
       curIndexInB = A.indexOf(aPtr++, curIndexInB + 1); //get the next character in A that is in B but after current pointer in B.
     }
   }

   return sol;
}
```

Does this look correct?

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

I tried your algorithm , and it seems it doesnt work as you want , i can suggest you the following idea :

First, you take the B and you try to extract all the possible parts that you can, for example for "BAZ" you can extract

> { "B", "A", "Z", "BA", "AZ", "BAZ" }

Secondly, for each element of the extracted elements from B, you will see if it's contained in A, if yes then the number will increment, and in the end you can return that number

I made this algorithm with these steps, and it works

- The algorithm :

  ```
     public static int algorithm(String A, String B) {
     int number = 0;

     // extracting all possible substrings from B
     ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

     for (int i = 0; i < B.length(); i++) {
         for (int j = i + 1; j <= B.length(); j++) {
               elements.add(B.substring(i, j));
         }
     }
     // for each element see if its contained in A
     for (String e : elements) {
         if (A.contains(e)) {
             number++;
         }
     }
     return number;
  }
  ```
- The main

  ```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String A ="ZAZA"; 
         String B = "BAZ";
         System.out.println(algorithm(A,B));
     }
  ```
- The output :

  3

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is generally sound. However, your first attempt has some issues, mostly in these lines:

```
 while(curIndexInB < B.length && aPtr < A.length()){
   curIndexInB = A.indexOf(aPtr++, curIndexInB + 1); 
 }
```

Obviously you need to check for the `charAt(aPtr)`, not `aPtr`. Also, this will run into issues when the character is not found, i.e. `curIndexInB` is -1. Finally, you should only be incrementing `aPtr` when the character is found.

I took the liberty of restructuring your code a little and it seems to work fine:

```
public static int algorithm(String A, String B)
{
   int sol = 0;

   for(int aPtr=0; aPtr<A.length(); sol++)
   {
     for(int curIndexInB=0; curIndexInB<B.length() && aPtr<A.length(); aPtr++)
     {
       int nextIndexInB = B.indexOf(A.charAt(aPtr), curIndexInB); 
         if(nextIndexInB == -1)
         {
             if(curIndexInB == 0) return -1;
             break;
         }
         curIndexInB = nextIndexInB + 1;
     }
   }

   return sol;
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(algorithm("ZAZA", "BAZ"));
```

Output:

```
3
```